# How to include “within” and “between” predictors in a model?

Tags: coordinates, spatial, glm, poisson, glmmtmb

I have a dataset of fish caught in several points in 120 lakes. In each lake, we collected fish at random places (points), resulting in approximately 800 fish observations. Among other factors, I would like to account fish variation (e.g. density of individuals captured) “between” and “within” lakes, since I have the coordinates for each fish observation and also for each lake.

How is it possible to include “within” and “between” lake variation in a model to verify which one is more important for fish response?

This is an example of my dataset:

| observation | lake | point | Xcoord.lake | Ycoord.lake | Xcoord.point | Ycoord.point | fish | factor1 | factor2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | lake1 | 1 | 453497 | 6166094 | 453022 | 6166137 | 100 | 37.10 | 158.9 |
| 2 | lake1 | 2 | 453025 | 6166110 | 453022 | 6166137 | 95 | 15.7 | 105.1 |
| 3 | lake1 | 3 | 453093 | 6166079 | 453022 | 6166137 | 73 | 0 | 170.0 |
| 4 | lake2 | 1 | 493269 | 6319292 | 493269 | 6318708 | 0 | 5.1 | 185.7 |
| 5 | lake2 | 2 | 493269 | 6319292 | 493568 | 6318542 | 10 | 10.7 | 129.4 |
| 6 | lake2 | 3 | 493269 | 6319292 | 493627 | 6318531 | 8 | 20.8 | 257.3 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 798 | lake120 | 1 | 517966 | 6143495 | 517967 | 6143454 | 252 | 50.2 | 326.9 |
| 799 | lake120 | 2 | 517966 | 6143495 | 517969 | 6143379 | 158 | 33.8 | 196.4 |
| 800 | lake120 | 3 | 517966 | 6143495 | 517972 | 6143510 | 300 | 87.5 | 93.2 |

I was trying something like:

```
fit <-glmmPQL(fish ~ factor1 + factor2,  random = ~1|lake, data = data, 
              family = poisson, correlation = corExp(form = ~ Xcoord.point + Ycoord.lake))
```

But I don’t know if this responds my question.

I really appreciate any help!